# Getting the week number of month using time stamp format '2016-11-22 14:35:51' using SPARK SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a time stamp column which has records of type '2016-11-22 14:35:51' in SPARK SQL. Would someone help me with retrieving the week number of month for the given time stamp format?

I have tried,

> **SELECT** timestamp, DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, 'u') AS WEEK **FROM** table_1;

But it gives the wrong output as,

```
timestamp  |  WEEK
2016-11-22 |  2
```

Appreciate if someone coulkd help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong literal, you need to use `W` instead of `u`.

The literal **`u`** refers to the **day number of week.**

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("select current_timestamp() as time, date_format(current_timestamp,'W') as week").show
// +--------------------+----+
// |                time|week|
// +--------------------+----+
// |2017-01-09 13:46:...|   2|
// +--------------------+----+

scala> sqlContext.sql("select to_date('2017-01-01') as time, date_format(to_date('2017-01-01'),'W') as week").show
// +----------+----+
// |      time|week|
// +----------+----+
// |2017-01-01|   1|
// +----------+----+
```

If you have more doubts, you can always refer to the [official documentation of SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) in Java.